# appcfg.py update does not store cookie and keeps asking for password

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, windows-8, mingw32

Based on the document appcfg.py update will ask for the password for the first time and then store it in a cookie and not ask for it subsequently.

This is not working for me and I have to enter the password every time. The ~/.appcfg_cookies is always empty for me (I have confirmed write permission to it).

I am running this on windows via the MinGW for windows 8/amd.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more like an issue to be submitted to http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list.

In the meantime I suggest you to use OAuth2, using the `--oauth2` option. See [Passwordless Login with OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#oauth) for more details.

Comment: Yes, that is what I landed up doing OAuth2 makes good sense and worked well.. Thanks.